# Angular circular svg progress bar gradient stroke

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg

I am trying to build an angular directive which will display circular progress of something.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrz822x0/)

I want to have repetitive linear gradient gradient light dark lines in the stroke something like

Some code from fiddle

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <circular-progress-bar background="#25714A" size="84" stroke-width="5" 
                            complete="60" total="100"></circular-progress-bar>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: ok, so what is the question?

Comment: @unobf How can I achieve what is showing in the image

Answer (score 0):

I'm not incredibly familiar with working with SVGs like this, but maybe this idea can help.

Can you:

- Not use strokes to show the progress.
- Make a pie slice sandwich. Use a background circle and a foreground circle, the foreground circle diameter being the width of your background circle minus 2x your current stroke.
- Use a pie slice as the "meat" in the sandwich and decrease it's range as the progress gets to 100%.

This will allow you to have the background circle have a striped background and have it animate. This is definitely possible with CSS. Chris Coyier shows how here: http://css-tricks.com/uniqlo-stripe-hovers/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle example with d3

http://jsfiddle.net/5yhgyyq9/4/

You just need to play with the `percentage` variable to get it to show you the appropriate amount. You could adapt this to work with standard SVG too.

```
var radius = 100,
    padding = 10,
    radians = 2 * Math.PI;

var dimension = (2 * radius) + (2 * padding),
    points = 50, percentage = .77;

var angle = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, points-1])
    .range([0, radians]);

var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .tension(0)
    .radius(radius)
    .angle(function(d, i) { 
        if (i < (points*percentage + 1)) {
            return angle(i);
        }
    });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", dimension)
    .attr("height", dimension)
.append("g");

svg.append("path").datum(d3.range(points))
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (radius + padding) + ", " + (radius + padding) + ")");
```

By adding a gradient element to the SVG

```
<svg>
    <linearGradient id="mygradient" x1="0" y1="1" x2="6.123233995736766e-17" y2="0" gradientTransform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#006d00"></stop>
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#00ff00"></stop>
        <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#006d00"></stop>
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#00ff00"></stop>
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#006d00"></stop>
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#00ff00"></stop>
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#006d00"></stop>
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#00ff00"></stop>
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#006d00"></stop>
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#00ff00"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#006d00"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

and a style, you can get a gradient stroke

```
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: url('#mygradient');
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke-linecap:round;
}
```

I will leave it as an exercise for you to figure out exactly what gradient works for you

Comment: The stripe lines are not there